# Lavacharts render chart to image file

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, charts

I have tried searching all over google for the solution but no luck. 
My question is, is it possible to save the rendered chart of lavacharts into image file? I'm trying to display the chart into PDF but it seems PDF does not accept lavacharts. So is there anyway to achieve this?

Im doing this on laravel my codes for controller is this

```
$nurse_admin_to_doctor_ratio  = Lava::DataTable();                                   
$nurse_admin_to_doctor_ratio->addStringColumn('')
        ->addNumberColumn('Nurse to Doctors Staff Ratio')
        ->addNumberColumn('Administrator to Doctors Staff Ratio')
        ->addRow(['Your Pratice', $nurse_to_doctor_ratio, $administrator_to_doctor_ratio])
        ->addRow(['Benchmark Same Size Practice', 2, 20])
        ->addRow(['Benchmark All', 4, 30]);

Lava::ColumnChart('staffratio', $nurse_admin_to_doctor_ratio,[
        'titleTextStyle' => [
                'color' => '#eb6bb2c',
                'fontSize' => 10
        ],
         'legend' => [
            'position' => 'top'
        ],
        'barGroupWidth' => "10%"
    ]);
```

My view

```
<div id="staffratio"></div>


   {!! Lava::render('ColumnChart', 'staffratio', 'staffratio', true) !!}
```

So instead of displaying it on view, I want to store the generated chart into image file. How would you store the render the chart into image file?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem. I managed to pass the charts to img using 'png' => true in the chart option but I still can't print them to a PDF. Did you reach to a solution?